# If $A$ and $B$ are commuting matricies, does the basis of $B$ block diagonalise $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, diagonalization, block-matrices

Let $A,B\in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ and $[A,B]=0$. Let the set of eigenvectors of $B$ with eigenvalue $\beta^{(i)}$ be denoted by $\{\underline{b}_j^{(i)}\}$. We can construct the $i$-th projector via the outer product
$$
P_i \doteq \sum_j^{g^{(i)}} \underline{b}_j^{(i)}\left(\underline{b}_j^{(i)}\right)^{\dagger},
$$
where $g^{(i)}$ denotes the degeneracy of the $i$-th eigenvalue.

**Is it true that, with the projector defined as above**
$$
\Lambda_i \doteq P_i^{-1} A P_i = \cdots \oplus A_i \oplus \cdots,
$$
**i.e. $A_i$ is the $i$-th block of the block diagonal representation of $A$ such that**
$$
\Lambda \doteq P^{-1} A P \doteq \sum_i P_i^{-1} A P_i = A_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus A_i \oplus \cdots \oplus A_n =
\begin{pmatrix}
A_1 & \cdots & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & \cdots & A_i & \cdots & 0\\
\vdots &\ddots & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots\\
0 & \cdots & 0 & \cdots & A_n
\end{pmatrix},
$$
**where $A_i \in \mathbb{C}^{g^{(i)}\times g^{(i)}}$?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. If $B$ has the above eigenbasis, in that basis, $[A,B]=0$ gives $\lambda_j A_{ij} - \lambda_i A_{ij}=0,$ where $A_{ij}$'s are the block matrices, so the block is identically $0$ for $A_{ij}$ with different $i$ and $j$.

Comment: Thanks! I worked out your answer and it works just like explained. However, don't you mean $A_{ij}$ is the block diagonal matrix (and not matri**ces**)?

Comment: I was too lazy to typeset :) $\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
A_{11} & A_{12} & \dots & A_{1n}\\
A_{21} & A_{22} & \dots & A_{2n}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \dots & \vdots\\
A_{n1} & A_{n2} & \dots & A_{nn}
\end{array}\right)$ is what I meant. So $A_{ii}$ will form the block diagonal matrix.

Comment: Indeed, I probably should have referred to $A_{ij}$'s as matrix blocks (instead of block matrices). Each of those can be rectangular though.